# Slow I/O rhel 5.1 on hyper-v 2012 r2

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, rhel5, informix

I have RHEL 5.1 server with informixDB is virtualized on Hyper-V 2012 R2 when i make request on database it's very very slow and my disk host database is 99% use....

Here iostat result during request DB: [iostat during request of DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYZDM.png)

%util: 98% with read of 1mb/s it's very poor performance...

RHEL is configured with "noop" I/O scheduler and vhdx are mount in SCSI controller.

Infrastructure: 3x Hyper-V 2012 R2 with VMQ disabled. VM run with fixed vhdx and store in SAN Equallogic (RAID 50) connected at 10Gbps. SAN Volume are mapped in iSCSI on each hyper-v host.

Comment: What are you asking?  What does 98% util mean?  98% of what?  iostat during?  Is this a question about Informix?  About a SAN?  About Windows Server 2012?  Hyper-V?  Please narrow this down if you want us to help you.

Comment: Problem is: disk is use at 98%. But i dont know why ... on this disk i have informix database, and the virtual machine is hosting on Hyper-V 2012 R2 with SAN storage but i think it's not a problem with SAN because I/O on SAN are not high.

Comment: 98% what?  Use of space? Anything over 80% is going to be a serious performance hit.  RAM, CPU ok?

Comment: 98% utilization of disk. Space is 70% not a problem.
RAM: 4Gb and used 41Mb
Mem:   4054984k total,  4029968k used,    25016k free,    31104k buffers
CPU: 
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 74.9%id, 24.7%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st